# What is the difference between fields and params in the Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/) and [Code Sample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/AdAccountAdSetsPostCreateCampaign.py)

In the documentation above there are only two parameters.
However, in the code example they are using fields as parameters.

I tried searching the docs but I'm still unclear on how fields and params are different.
Are they completely interchangeable or are there specific times to use each?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried searching the docs but I'm still unclear on how fields and params are different. Are they completely interchangeable or are there specific times to use each?

**Fields** are the specific data elements you can request about an object.

A user’s e-mail address, a post’s message, a page’s cover photo – those are fields.

**Parameters** allow you to limit the selection of data, based on specific criteria.

You request a page’s feed, but you only want posts from a specific time frame - then you use parameters like `since` and `until`, for example.

---

If you are familiar with basic SQL, you could use this as an analogy: Fields would be the column names you specify after SELECT; Parameters would be the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The analogy does help. Is that a standard way of using these terms of specific to Facebook? I'm still unsure why in the code example they're filling the params json with fields.

Comment: I guess they decided to use the terminology “parameter” in that place, because it is about _creating_ a campaign. That kinda makes sense; although that is not terminology they use consistently, in other places often they use fields for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Facebook Support and this was their answer:

> Parameters are inputs to an API that specify constraints on the range
>   of data that will be returned (time ranges, specific ids etc.). Fields
>   are what are returned by the API, if you want specific fields to be
>   returned, these can be specified by adding something like
>   "fields=id,name..." to an API.
>
> Parameters and fields are not interchangeable.